# PowerShell: Remove spaces before and after multiple Strings in Text

Tags: string, powershell

Right now I'm reading a File from line to line, and searching a string in it.

If I found a right Line, I just needed 1 word from the String, so I could delete everything but that string. Now I have multiple Strings int the Line which are separated by Spaces. The Problem is that the Line has a lot of spaces at the start so I can't split the sentence or remove all spaces because then the multiple words would merge to one. Here's an example:

Some Lines in the File for example:

```
Network 1:
              protocols ping ssh icmp
              names PC001 PC002 PC003
Network 2:
              protocols ping ssh icmp
...
```

Code:

```bsh
Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object{
    $line = $_
    if($line -like "*protocols*"){
        $Protocols = $line.Replace("protocol ", "")
        $Protocols = $Protocol.Replace(" ", "")
    }
}
```

I know it isn't the best but I'm open to improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
$Protocols = $Protocol.Replace(" ", "")
```

With:

```
$Protocols = $Protocol.trimstart().trimend()
```

Comment: Ok maybe I should've made it more clear, the file is Huge, and there are multiple "protocls" in there. All this is inside a function that gets the Line i need. I can't take the whole File.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

```
$file = 'D:\test\regtest.txt'

$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText( $file )
while( ($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null ) {
    if( $line -like '*protocols*' ) {
        $result = $line -replace '^.*protocols +(.*)', '$1' | ? { $_ } 
        $result
    }
}
[void]$reader.Close()
```

Comment: Ok maybe I should've made it more clear, the file is Huge, and there are multiple "protocls" in there. All this is inside a function that gets the Line i need. I can't take the whole File.

Comment: Thank you for the new approach, but I have a Question, what exactly is the difference between Foreach and the [System.IO.File] you use?

Comment: System.io is the fastest method for file access. if you handle with huge files, it's recommended.